# jquery dialog parameter not passing in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, safari

I'm using the below code to pass an error message to a javascript function to be displayed as a dialog. For some reason it works in IE but doesn't work in Safari. The parameter is passed as empty. I'm using vb.net and jquery 1.11.1

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "showalert", "enroll_failed('" & sReturnMessage.ToString & "');", True)
```

javascript function

```
function enroll_failed(errorMessage) {
         $("#error_error").html(errorMessage);
         $("#error_error").bPopup();

    }
```

when i debug in IE i can see the errorMessage is populated with the correct message but in Safari it is always empty. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you console out the error message is it available? What if you use .text() instead of .html()? This is an odd issue which I don't think is related to bPopup().

Comment: @bencripps i've tried .text as well. The problem here is that it seems as though the function enroll_field is not receiving the value of errorMessage. if i put a breakpoint where the functino is invoked i can see the error message but for some reason it never reaches the function.